# Why does USA not diminish its NATO related expenses in order to persuade other NATO members to contribute more?

Tags: united-states, military, nato

At the NATO summit from 2017 (Brussels), Donald Trump emphasized that many NATO members are not contributing enough ([source](http://edition.cnn.com/2017/05/25/politics/trump-nato-financial-payments/)):

> Twenty-three of the 28 member nations are still not paying what they
>   should be paying and what they are supposed to be paying for their
>   defense. This is not fair to the people and taxpayers of the United
>   State

This is not the first time when the USA President said this.

[This article](http://www.economist.com/blogs/graphicdetail/2017/02/daily-chart-11) dives into details by showing graphs related to military expenditures of NATO countries reported to their GDP and confirms what Donald Trumps has emphasized:

> The United States has a point in noting that its commitment is
>   disproportionately large. Last year it spent 3.6% of its GDP on
>   defence, the highest ratio of any NATO member (and the highest total
>   military budget in the world by a hefty margin). That is almost double
>   the target of 2% of GDP that NATO members all agreed to in 2006. At
>   the time six members reached the threshold; last year five did.

**Question:** Wouldn't diminishing of USA NATO related expenses force the other countries to compensate (at least, obey the 2% of GDP agreement)?

Comment: Just a note it is not required for 2% GDP to be contributed and the agreement is that the countries would try/work their way up to it.

Comment: @SCFi - I did not know that. In my country (Romania) that was quite a debate for allocating 2% for 2017 and many agreed that we should make the effort since the country is located within the Eastern border of NATO, so close to Russian Federation. The media presented the threshold as a "must", rather than "nice to have".

Comment: Are you under the (mistaken) impression that there is a NATO army that countries are supposed to pay different amounts of money for? The defense spending of the US is a US decision that has nothing to do with NATO.

Comment: @Peter - no, but I kept hearing about the 2% threshold and the necessity to counteract Russia on the Eastern flank (there was a list of three "threats" for NATO, but I cannot find the reference - Russia was one of them).

Comment: @SCFi - The target date for it was 1974 or something like that though for the founding members

Comment: The 2% goal is a means for subsidizing the arms industries. The "threats" are invented or provoked. Just compare military spending per GDP in the 1980s, and you can already guess the economic need of ending the Russian-Western honeymoon 1990 to circa 2003.

Comment: And of course, the USA uses its military for lots of things that fall outside the scope of the NATO. If the USA cuts its budget, the other NATO members won't be pressured at all to replace the USA in these functions.

Comment: Presumably the US government believes that a certain level of defense is necessary.  They would prefer that others pay more towards that defense, but given a choice between paying more and weakening the defense, they choose the former.